# OneToThree django model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have a classic model containing some contact data (mail, addr, names, ...), and an other which is supposed to link to three contacts (an admin, an owner, a tech). A contact can be registered as admin and as tech for example.

```
class Contact(django.db.models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  country = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  family_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)


class Product(... Some parents)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  contacts ?
```

I don't know how to link 3 contacts to my other Model ... and generate a form with a queryset already existing.

Some advices ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use foreign keys
example:

```
class Product(... Some parents)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  admin = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="admins")
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="owners")
  tech = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="techs")
```

if you want to generate the form use a modelform

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model=Product
```

the select widgets will be filled automatically

EDIT: to display your contact in a human friendly way use

```
class Contact(django.db.models.Model):
    <usual stuff>
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.firstname  #  or any field you wish
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#str
if you use python 3 replace unicode by str

Comment: God save the maazza queen ...
Bah, not used to stackoverflow.
I tried without 'related_name', I'll have to rtfm, thanks much, two days on this problem. It seems to work now :) Thank you

Comment: Displayed fields on my page are actually "Contact object" ... How could I display the username stored in user instead ?

Comment: see my edit, also which version of python do you use ?

Comment: It's a 2.7 with a django 1.7 (Yeah, old version I know...)
Thanks